# PHP - Call class function from another class

Tags: php

I am developing an app where I need to log the proccess.
So I was loggin from *main.php* and now I need to log from another class (*class_TestingLog.php*)

Next code is how I am trying. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**main.php**

```
[...]

#Logging class
include_once("./classes/class_log.php"); 
$Class_Log = New Class_Log();

#TestingLog Class
include_once("./classes/class_testingLog.php");
$Class_TestingLog = New Class_TestingLog(); 

[...]

$Class_Log->FreeLog("Test log");
$Class_TestingLog->AnyFuncion();`

[...]
```

**class_log.php**

```
[...]

public function FreeLog($text)
{
    // echo $text . "\n"; #mistake
    $this->outputText .= text; #correct one
}

[...]
```

**class_testingLog.php**

```
private $Class_Log = '';

[...]

public function __construct()
{
    #Requires
    require_once("./classes/class_log.php");

    $this->Class_Log = New Class_Log();
}

public function AnyFuncion()
{
    var_dump($this); #From real file
    $this->Class_Log->FreeLog("Test log from another classs");
}

[...]
```

**Browser output**

```
Test log
```

**Browser output expected**

```
Test log
Test log from another classs
```

===========================================================================

## **EDIT**

I made an error copying FreeLog();
It stores the parameter string value into a private variable instead echo the variable.

Comment: the code above, in isolation, works - see https://eval.in/882009. Are you getting any errors or warnings as well? Perhaps a include did not work or something? Have you got PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: No, any warning or error. Got this at the first lines of main.php: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Why not just extend your class_testingLog to class_log? instead of calling it again which is redundant

Comment: I will test @hungrykoala, I am relatively new in PHP Classes. Did not worked yet with extend.

Comment: Read about inheritance. It's one of the features of OOP that should be used often to reduce redundant codes.

Comment: Thank you @hungrykoala, I will do it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `require_once` statement inside `__construct` for `Class_TestingLog` is invalid and unnecessary. As both files are in the same directory it should be `"class_log.php"` not `"./classes/class_log.php"`. There is no need for it anyway, as when you include them both in `main.php` it is loaded already. So try it without the `require_once`.

**EDIT:** As discussed in chat do it like this:

in `main.php`:

```
$Class_TestingLog = New Class_TestingLog($Class_Log);
```

in `class_testingLog.php`:

```
public function __construct($ClassLog)
{
    $this->Class_Log = $ClassLog;
}
```

This will use the same instance inside the `Class_TestingLog` class as on the `main.php`.

Comment: Tested it: Warning: require_once(./class_log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in... No warning with ./classes/class_log.php

Comment: @JordiHuertas fixed it. remove `./`  also, there is no need to use `require_once` anyway.

Comment: Without require_once do the same like the example post. It is not loggin anything.

Comment: @JordiHuertas It is working on my localhost, the problem should be somewhere else then.

Comment: Thank you, I will test from the beggining. Really the script is already very big, it has cost me quite reduce it.

Comment: Let me ask you: The script starts and pass throught AnyFunction() (Tested var_dumping anything after freelog function). It is ignoring FreeLog for any reason. I have at the first lines of main.php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); . Is there anything else that shows me more warnings or errors?

Comment: @JordiHuertas Try `var_dump($this);` inside `AnyFuncion()`

Comment: Edited the post and copied the var_dump

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156993/discussion-between-mega6382-and-jordi-huertas).